# Юникс время в js

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

Хочу написать простую программу для вывода погоды и тд, но возникли трудности с выводом времени(а именно с разницей времени в часовых поясах)

```
      var sunrise = data.sys.sunrise;
      var datesr = new Date(sunrise*1000);
      datesr = datesr.getHours() + ":" + datesr.getMinutes() + ":" + datesr.getSeconds();

      var sunset = data.sys.sunset;
      var datess = new Date(sunset*1000);
      datess = datess.getHours()  + ":" + datess.getMinutes() + ":" + datess.getSeconds();
```

Хочу вывести  время восхода и захода солнца(openweathermap). Но правильно выводит только то что находится в моем часовом поясе, все остальное смешается на разницу между моим поясом и другим

Попробовал и так

```
      var sunrise = data.sys.sunrise;
      var datesr = new Date(sunrise*1000);
      datesr = datesr.getUTCHours() + data.timezone/3600 + ":" + datesr.getMinutes() + ":" + datesr.getSeconds();

      var sunset = data.sys.sunset /* + data.timezone */ ;
      var datess = new Date(sunset*1000);
      datess = datess.getUTCHours() + data.timezone/3600  + ":" + datess.getMinutes() + ":" + datess.getSeconds();
```

В этом случае выводится верно,но лишь частично, так как появляются отрицательные часы

Почему то мне кажется что я туплю и есть короткий вариант решения это задачи.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

```
      var sunrise = data.sys.sunrise;
      var datesr = new Date((sunrise + data.timezone)*1000);
      datesr = datesr.getUTCHours() + ":" + datesr.getMinutes() + ":" + datesr.getSeconds();

      var sunset = data.sys.sunset /* + data.timezone */ ;
      var datess = new Date((sunset + + data.timezone)*1000);
      datess = datess.getUTCHours() + ":" + datess.getMinutes() + ":" + datess.getSeconds();
```

вот так выходит как надо